# TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, typeerror

I have looked at other threads and can't figure out what's wrong. All the answers are too complex for me to process well.

I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

and I don't know why.

Here is a snippet:

```py
calcWhat = 4
elif o == "^":
    pwr = int(input("To the power of what? "))
    pwr = pwr - 1 #So that if it's one then it doesnt multiply at all
    ans = calcWhat * calcWhat
    for pwr in range:
        ans = ans + (calcWhat * calcWhat)
```

I think that's correct code, but I don't even get to see without fixing this error!

What is wrong?

Comment: People are probably going to dislike this post because it's a duplicate of other posts. but I just need less complicated answers.

Comment: your loop should look like this `for pp in range(pwr):` range creates a sequence of numbers. If pwr is 2, then range is (0,2)

Comment: `range` is the "type" in the error. You are perhaps looking for the generator `range()`?

Comment: They're going to downvote this because any tutorial on looping in Python shows the correct way to use `range()`.

Comment: `for pwr in range` is incorrect.  You have to give an actual numeric range value, such as `range(5)` or `range(100)`.

Comment: Why do you need the loop? It's just `ans = calcWhat * calcWhat * pwr`. BTW, you're not calculating a power when you add each time.

Comment: @G.Anderson `range` does not create a generator

Comment: I decided to go the way of @Barmar and do `ans = calcWhat * calcWhat * pwr`. I was going to do that but was worried it wouldn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to iterate over `range` which is a `type` (as the error mentions). You probably want to call the function `range()` and give it the range limit. In your case it would be:

```
for _ in range(pwr):
```

Comment: I would have used this, but I decided to take @Barmar's advice and do `ans = calcWhat * calcWhat * pwr`. But since it was a good answer I will mark as accepted :)